# How do you read in binary data files where the "words" have different byte lengths?

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to read in a binary file using Java.  I am currently using

```
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream(new File("file")));
```

I know that the first 48 bytes is a header.  The first 20 bytes is a string and I am able to read that in like this:

```
    readByte = new byte[20];
    dis.read(readByte);
    string = new String(readByte);
    System.out.println(string);
```

Then the next 10 bytes are a decimal (not 100% sure of format - I'm guessing double will work, but I may have to discover this empirically).  I have been trying to figure out how to get this number out, but I am new to Java.  It seems like this should be relatively straight-forward, but I am having no luck.  I have tried a few ideas mentioned on other threads but I just can't get it to work and only get garbled gibberish out.

Thanks!

Comment: Decimal *in what format*?

Comment: The next 10 bytes are a decimal?? What decimal number needs 10 bytes to hold it? Can you tell us what file format you're parsing so we check what's really expected from written code?

Comment: It's a time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two possible ways to selve this :

1- since you know the length of the fields then you should should use defined functions of DataInputStream to read 
[check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) this can be useful only if you want only specific fields of the header

2- or you can read the whole header and extract field information's, the better is to use it in a class, use `java.nio.ByteBuffer` class to make conversions

```
public class Header{
     byte headerBytes;
     Header(byte[] hBytes){
          headerBytes = hBytes;
     }
     // here you implement getters/setters for your header 
     public String getFirstField(){
           byte[] field = new byte[20];// you can declare this as a class var it would be better
           for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
                field[i] = this.headerBytes[i];   
           return new String(field/*,maybe put the encoding here */);
     }
     public Integer getAnIntField(pos start){// just a example how to get Integer 
           for (int i = start; i<4; i++)
                field[i] = this.headerBytes[i];
           return new Integer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt());   
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! that really helped.

Comment: glad to know that :]